# Ever since 5.0 was installed my text message notification always plays the default sound

Tags: notifications

Ever since 5.0 was installed my text message notification always plays the default sound.  I  have tried deleting and recreating the contact but no change.  When I check to see what notification sound is selected it's the one I want.  I can even play it and then save the contact information.  Still, when a message comes in it plays the default message tone.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The custom contact ringtone  (at least it sounds like a custom contact ringtone) presumably only works with the default messaging app. Are you using the default messaging app?

Comment: Please seek clarifications using comments on the question.